# How to uningore directories in .prettierignore

Tags: prettier

I need to make prettier format code only in one directory, omitting the rest. I set up my `./.prettierignore` like this:

```
/*
!/some/dir/
```

but everything in `/some/dir/` is ignored too when i run `prettier --write .`

Comment: Where (relative to `/some/dir`) the `.prittierignore` file is located? (You might want to read through [this](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/578))

Comment: @Christian.K .prittierignore lies at root

Comment: I guess, the question I was trying to ask is this: is "some"  a directory at the same a directory in same directory that `.prittierignore` is in? But anyway, I'm just guessing at a reason...